# How can I set priority using Case-When in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

For a project at work, I need to be able to prioritize the version of a magazine a customer gets.

If someone is qualified for more than one version of the brochure because of the categories they bought from, here is the priority:

1. Women's
2. Men's
3. Media
4. Best of

So, if someone bought a women's sweater, a DVD, a birdfeeder and men's shoes, they would get the women's brochure.  I'm pretty sure a Case/When statement would be used, but I'm not 100% on that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please put a bit more work into describing what the input data and expected output result look like? - As in, other columns? We don't need all of them if there are tens or hundreds of them but just a couple more to make clear how you're expecting all of the data to be mapped through the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CASE expression

```
SELECT 
col,
CASE    
    WHEN col='Women''s' then 1
    WHEN col='Men''s' then 2
    WHEN col='Media' then 3
    WHEN col='Best of' then 4
END as priority
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table which assigns priority to category

```
select * 
into #categories
from(
    values
        (4,'Women''s'),
        (3,'Men''s'  ),
        (2,'Media'   ),
        (1,'Best of' )
    ) t(priority, title);
```

And now every customer gets the title of the higest priority he bouhgt.

```
select customer
  , title = (select title 
     from #categories c2
     where max(c.priority) = c2.priority)
from ( -- sample data
    values
        (10,'Women''s'),
        (10,'Men''s'),
        (10,'Media'  ),
        (10,'Best of' ),
        (20,'Men''s'),
        (20,'Best of' )
    ) tbl(customer, category)
join #categories c
    on c.title=tbl.category
group by customer
```